# Windows Forms - count subitems in listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview, listviewitem

I have this issue, when selected multiple times one product in UI then in listview it apears multiple times...on multiple rows
I want to be one row with cappuccino with quantity and it price

[image]

I have a list of products:

```
public List<Product> productsList1;
```

and then

```
foreach (var item in productsList)
            {
                //listView1.Items.Add(item.ToString());
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(item.Name);

                lvi.SubItems.Add(item.Price.ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

The list has only name of product and it's price.How to in listview to count how much it appears and if we have 2 cappuccino and 1 late to have 2 rows in listview and count their quantity:

Cappuccino ---> 2 ----> 1 Euro

Late -----> 1 >>>> 2 Euro

Answer (score 1):

In Linq you can do a group by and sum.

```
        var nl = from pl in productsList1
                 group pl by new { pl.Name }  into g
                 select new { Product = g.Key, Quantity = g.Count(), PricePerLine = g.Sum( ss => ss.Price)};
```

You can then iterate this list

```
foreach(var item in nl)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(item.Name);

    //Quantity
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(item.Quantity .ToString());

    //Price per line item
    lvi.SubItems.Add(item.PricePerLine .ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: I don’t have field Quantity in the class, is there any way to count the names which are equals and then to set the count in the list view